# Create "M-x" command shortcuts in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Some of the commands in `emacs` are so long to type.

Still, I'd like them as `M-x` commands (not keyboard shortcuts) as I have so many, I'd start stumble on them.

And, the old ones should not be removed. It'll take a while getting used to the new ones.

Only way I could think of, doing it one by one like this. Better way?

```
(defun icd (dict) "Alias for ispell-change-dictionary"
  (interactive "sDictionary: ")
  (ispell-change-dictionary (downcase dict)))
```

Comment: Yeah... if you consider living in what I have affectionately nicknamed "reality"?

Comment: I'm not going to read that just because you think some digit is too low. If you think somewhere my behavior is not in line with the site's intentions then please bring that occasion to my attention. Until then, I'm not gonna say anything more about this clown "issue".

Comment: @DangKhoa: I stumbled over this old argument, and now I understand you a bit more. Back then, I had not realized how sensitive this reputation thing was. Well, nothing to get upset about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `defalias`:

```
(defalias 'bc 'emacs-lisp-byte-compile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before defining aliases for every command, you should use *ido-mode*

See here: [EmacsWiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings)

Comment: `ido-mode` doesn't work for `M-x`.  For that you'd want [smex](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex).

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
(setq completion-styles (append completion-styles '(initials)))
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map
            [?\M-\t] 'minibuffer-force-complete)
```

in your .emacs, then M-x icd M-TAB M-TAB will get you ispell-change-directory.  And next time around, a single M-TAB will be sufficient (because the cycling prefers entries that are found in the history).